# Define the location of Java fatal error log in runtime

Tags: java, logging, error-handling, location, fatal-error

is there any way to define the location of the fatal error logs in Java (hs_err_*.pid.log) in the runtime?
I know from [1] that I can set the location as parameter, but I want to change it in runtime.

Philip

[1] http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-Desktop/html/felog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp:

"Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are not recommended for casual use. These options are subject to change without notice."

From the same page, there is indication that that the **ErrorFile** option is **not manageable** through JConsole, so I wouldn't expect it to be modifiable through any other means.